# Error with memset when compiling c++ code for threads in android ndk

Tags: android, c++, pthreads

I have a Problem. I want to create a thread in Android 2.3.4 with the NDK r7. When I compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "System.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <pthread.h>

unsigned int CreateThread(void* function(void*) , void * context)
{   int         ret;
    pthread_t   thread;
    ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, function, context);
    if(ret != 0)
    {   return 0;
    }
    return (unsigned int) thread;
}
```

I get these error messages:

```
E:/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/include/stdarg.h:102: error: expected ';' before 'typedef'
In file included from E:/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/pthread.h:32, from jni/system.cpp:13:
E:/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h: In function 'int sigemptyset(sigset_t*)':
E:/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:84: error: 'memset' was not declared in this scope
E:/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h: In function 'int sigfillset(sigset_t*)':
E:/Code/Android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/signal.h:90: error: 'memset' was not declared in this scope
```

Did I miss to include or define something to get the memset errors ?

I am really not sure what the problem is and why the memset errors apear. I also tried including cstring but then I got a huge number of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I have my own class that has a filename that is called "string.h" and resides within my jni directory. Therefore the "string.h" that resides within the ndk and has the declaration of the necessary memset function (among others) is not being included.

The options were to either change the filename/name of my class or directly include the string.h from the ndk with a direct path.

I chose the first option and renamed my string class and try to not use standard file names for my classes from now on...

Comment: Actually I found the problem because someone else stumbled over it as well so I decided to leave the question as is. I wish sometimes more answers were on the net without being deleted as even some "localized questions" might be of use to some...